# Product of Factors Formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The product of the proper positive integer factors of $n$ can be written as $n^{(ax+b)/c}$, where $x$ is the number of positive divisors $n$ has, $c$ is a positive integer, and the greatest common factor of the three integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ is $1$. What is $a+b+c$?

I can not remember where I have seen this problem, but I can not solve it. How would you?

Comment: **Hint:**  If $p$ is a factor of $n$, then $q=\frac{n}{p}$ is also a factor of $n$ and unless if $n$ is a perfect square, then $p\neq q$

Comment: Or, maybe you could compute the product for the values $2,6,30$ of $n$ and then solve three equations in the three unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: Getting anywhere, djd?

Comment: Earth to djd; come in, please!